# Check value in angular array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Hello guys i cant find actually info about convert string to array and after check them.Im trying check have this post in usermeta or not. Before converting to array this string. But it doesnt work why?

```
$scope.like = function(id) {
    PostService.GetUserMeta(user).then(function(data) {
        var likes = '290 270'
        var check_likes = likes.split(" ");
        if (check_likes != id) {
            $http.jsonp('http://somesite.com/api/userplus/update_user_meta_vars/', {
                params: {
                    like_post: id + ',' + likes,
                    callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log('Id added to array');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('ID already in array');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: check_likes is an array and you are comparing check_likes != id please check this again. Use check_likes.indexOf(id) >= 0 for checking instead.

Comment: you can use regex,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in statement

```
if(check_likes != id)
```

Here `check_likes` is an array thus it will never be equal to `id`

I think you need to create a number array.

```
var check_likes = likes.split(" ").map(Number);
```

Then you can use [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check whether `id` exists in an array, it returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or `-1` if it is not present.

```
if (check_likes.indexOf(id) == -1){
    $http.jsonp(.....)
}else{
    console.log('ID already in array');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That really elegant way)

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare an object of type `Array` to a primitive data type like your `id` parameter.

Try wrapping your code inside a loop like so:

```
for(i = 0; i < check_likes.length; i++){
    if (check_likes[i] != id) {
           $http.jsonp('http://somesite.com/api/userplus/update_user_meta_vars/', {
            params: {
                like_post: id + ',' + likes,
                callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log('Id added to array');
        });
    } else {
        console.log('ID already in array');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$scope.like = function(id) {
    PostService.GetUserMeta(user).then(function(data) {
        var likes = '290 270'
        var check_likes = likes.split(" ");
        if (check_likes.indexOf(id) == -1) {
            $http.jsonp('http://somesite.com/api/userplus/update_user_meta_vars/', {
                params: {
                    like_post: id + ',' + likes,
                    callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log('Id added to array');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('ID already in array');
        }
    })
}
```

After splitting `likes` string you have an array of 2 strings, and you should check  that your id param is not in that array to execute your request. The `!=` would not work